# Shared preferences in android null pointer exception

Tags: android

I move from Activity A to Activity B by intent.I am storing some values in shared preferences in Activity B.In activity A oncreate() i am fetching the values of the shared preferences to compare with some conditions however it gives me null pointer exception as expected (As i do not go to Activity B).However i want to write a condition to fetch the data from shared preferences if the value is not null.Can some one please say how can i achieve this? Following is my code:

```
   In Activity B: 
               SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MerchantLogin.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("showdialog_login", "dontshow");
                editor.commit();
In Activity A:
            @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

      SharedPreferences prefs =null;
 prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginScreen.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();


if ((prefs.getString("showdialog_login", null).equalsIgnoreCase("dontshow")))
{

}
else if((prefs.getString("showdialog_login", null).equalsIgnoreCase("true")))
{

}
else if((prefs.getString("showdialog_login", null).equalsIgnoreCase("dummy")))
{

}
else
{
    editor.putString("showdialog_login", "false");
    editor.commit();
}

    }
```

However i get error at this line:

```
if ((prefs.getString("showdialog_login", null).equalsIgnoreCase("dontshow"))).How can i execute this block of code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use the constant as the first argument when comparing using `equals`, i.e.

```
"dontshow".equalsIgnoreCase(prefs.getString("showdialog_login", null))
```

You are getting the `NullPointerException` because the `showdialog_login` property is not yet set, i.e.

```
prefs.getString("showdialog_login", null)
```

returns `null`, because that's what you set the default value to.

Effectively, your condition is thus

```
null.equalsIgnoreCase("dontshow")
```

-which naturally ends up in a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks Zoltan u saved my lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of :

```
prefs.getString("showdialog_login", null)
```

Use:

```
prefs.getString("showdialog_login", "")
```

Because, if value for "showdialog_login" preference is not set, it will return null value and you might get NPE (Null pointer exception).

Answer (score 0):

In Activity A:

```
 static SharedPreferences prefs;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

      prefs = getSharedPreferences("showdialog_login",0);
      String ss= prefs.getString("showdialog_login", "default");
if ((ss.equalsIgnoreCase("dontshow")))
{

}
else if((ss.equalsIgnoreCase("true")))
{

}
else if((ss.equalsIgnoreCase("dummy")))
{

}
else
{
    editor.putString("showdialog_login", "false");
    editor.commit();
}

    }
```